# why does assigning value to array struct not working C

Tags: c, arrays, struct, malloc

Im am trying to write a program that collects the information of students. I am using an array of students(structs)

```
typedef struct {
  char name[50];
  struct Course* course;
}Student;
```

and in my main() i did this

```
Student* stds = (Student*) malloc(app.std_cnt * sizeof(*stds) );

getStdData(stds);
```

here is the getStdData function

```
void getStdData(struct Student *students){

 int i;
 char name[50];

 Student std;

 printf("\n");

 for(i = 0; i < app.std_cnt; i++){

    printf("std [%i] name : ",i+1);


    scanf("%s",&name);

    strcpy(std.name,name);

    students[i] = std;

 }
}
```

when i compile i get

```
Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.00.23026 for x86
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

gpa.c
gpa.c(124): error C2440: '=': cannot convert from 'Student' to 'Student'
```

can anyone tell me what i'm doing wrong?
and why is is complaning about a Student to Student conversion? are they not of the same type?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Difference between 'struct' and 'typedef struct' in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/612328/difference-between-struct-and-typedef-struct-in-c)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In C, `struct Student` and `Student` may be two different types. `Student` comes from your typedef and `struct Student` would come from

```
struct Student { /* ... */ };
```

So your function should be

```
void getStdData(Student *students)
```

For a good discussion of the situation, consider [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/612350/3444805).

Comment: how then can i print the array?

Comment: Just change the function declaration as I suggest (remove the `struct` from  `void getStdData(struct Student *students){`)

Comment: sorry...was asking something else.

Comment: I see, I was confused because it looks like your code is already printing the array, I didn't notice that you are just printing the index.